# How to create a React App without Create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, boilerplate

I'm a newbie with React, I have made a few apps using the create-react-app to help get me started(as followed by numerous tutorials). I heard that I now need to know how to create a react app from scratch without using the create-react-app boilerplate maker.

I know that i have to add a few sections such as:

- React
- React-dom
- Webpack
- Babel

here are the list of dependencies in my package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "react": "^16.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack": "^3.8.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    entry: {
        app:'./src/index',
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/static/'
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin(['app'])
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test:/\.js/ + /\.jsx?$/, 
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        }]
    }
}
```

My .babelrc file

```
{
    "presents":["env","react"]
}
```

I've followed a few tutorials on how to make a React app from scratch, but with no success. I have a feeling that my Webpack config is not correct.

Unfortunately I am still unable to run this project

Git link to repo:
https://github.com/tony2tones/scratch-react/tree/master

Comment: which version of webpack are you using?

Comment: 4.9.1. Although i was recommended to use version 3, not too sure if this has added to my problem

Comment: "I heard that I now need to know how to create a react app from scratch without using the create-react-app boilerplate maker" - where did you hear that? There's nothing wrong with using create-react-app for "serious" website building.

Comment: Check this tutorial for React v17 setup without create-react-app: https://frontendguruji.com/blog/how-to-setup-a-react-js-project-from-scratch-without-create-react-app/

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned earlier, you need an

```
index.js
```

and inside of it you will need to at least have:    `import React from 'react';`

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

and

```
`ReactDOM.render(whatever you want to render, wherever you want to render(preferably document.getElementById('root')))
```

This shows what the app should render when it gets a request

Hope this will help. it's my first answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing a few things.

1. To `build` your project, you can call `npm run build`.
2. You need to add a `index.html` file to be rendered in browser.
3. You need to add `start` in your script object inside `package.json` and do `npm install` again.

For 3, you can add, `"start": "webpack-dev-server"`
Then to run you node server, you can do it by `npm run start`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Bascially `Create-react-app` abstract the setup of `babel` and `webpack`.
If you want to setup those things directly and understand what is what. I recommend going through [this blog](https://medium.com/age-of-awareness/setup-react-with-webpack-and-babel-5114a14a47e9)