# How to manually configure a minimal setup for React without create-react-app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, react-scripts

I do not want to use `create-react-app`. So how can I configure a **minimal** working dev environment for a simple react app?

**Note:** I know I could likely just include everything [at runtime as JS](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html) (that is well documented), but I do not want this, as I still want a version that is usable *for production*!

I do **not** want:

- to have any minification ([see related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55160698/how-to-use-react-without-unsafe-inline-javascript-css-code))
- to have any concatenation (or, if it is easier to do, I may have all JS e.g. concatenated in a file)
- any older browser support than what I write as JS (so no transpilation that does this)
- any dev server (I can reload manually.)
- any live-reload or advanced dev features

I do want:

- to use React components
- (optionally) include JSX ([I know it's possible to use React without it](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html), but let's say that is the minimal advantage I want to take from React. Please do avise me, however, what additional steps for setup/config this would "cost" to include, so this answer is applicable to those who want JSX and those who do not.)

Basically, **I *just* want to use React**. Without all the fancy other stuff that comes around it!*

I am just asking this, because [the official React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) do not mention that possibility.

---

Attention: Reasoning following for those that wonder, why I'd wanted this.

* Actually, it sounds crazy too dismiss these convenient dev features etc. But I claim there are legitimate reasons/use cases for this. My is e.g. that all of this just is not usaable for me/breaks things, as [I am trying to build a browser extension with React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55160698/how-to-use-react-without-unsafe-inline-javascript-css-code).

---

Yes [I saw this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50565466/how-to-create-a-react-app-without-create-react-app), but unfortunately the user there is one step ahead of me and the answers are just very specific ones to *their* problem. I want to know the general things first, i.e. **what do I need** and **how to setup**?

Comment: Right, I know links are not a good example, but this quide is actually what I followed a while ago : **https://medium.freecodecamp.org/part-1-react-app-from-scratch-using-webpack-4-562b1d231e75**. 
Also, it took me 2 seconds to find how to build a browser extension with react: https://medium.com/@gilfink/building-a-chrome-extension-using-react-c5bfe45aaf36 and finally, take a look at your question, split it into small problems and solve them one bit at a time.

Comment: you might want to look at [htm](https://github.com/developit/htm) ..and a random blog post.. [htm-2-for-javascript](https://matwrites.com/htm-2-for-javascript/)

Comment: Check this tutorial for React v17 setup without create-react-app: https://frontendguruji.com/blog/how-to-setup-a-react-js-project-from-scratch-without-create-react-app/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Preqrequisites:

- Node.js (npm) or yarn installed on your computer or as executable file

---

So for a pretty minimal setup you'd want to...

1. Initialize a folder

- `cd path/to/my/folder`
- `npm init`

2. Create an index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="./node_modules/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
        <script src="./node_modules/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
        <script src="./dist/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

3. Then you'd  want to `npm install --save` ...

- react
- react-dom
- webpack
- webpack-cli
- @babel/core
- babel-loader
- @babel/preset-react

`npm install --save react react-dom`
`npm install --save-dev webpack webpack-cli @babel/core babel-loader @babel/preset-react`

4. Create `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

5. Create webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

6. Edit `package.json` scripts to build

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode development"
  },
```

7. Write your root component

Create a `src/components` folder and then create your `src/components/app.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

export function App() {

  return (
    <div>
      Hello, world!
    </div>
  );
}
```

8. Write your ReactDOM renderer in `src/index.js` (note .js, not jsx - webpack wont find the file otherwise, without more configurations):

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { App } from "./components/app.jsx";

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

9. Build: `npm run build`
10. Open your `path/to/my/folder/index.html` in a modern browser

And you're done! You can now add any convenient add-ons you wish without any undesirable bloat. I recommend **TypeScript**.

For anyone reading that need to **support older browsers**, simply follow these two steps:

1. `npm install @babel/preset-env`
2. Edit `.babelrc` and add @babel/preset-env to your presets:

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you are just not really covering whether I can "save" some complexity/JS files if I do not use JSX. Or is it always included in react and thus I may not even use it without React?