# How use Create React App with custom template?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npx

I'm learning ReactJS, but in all the tutorials it says that the way to create a new react app is this:

```
npx create-react-app //name of my app
```

but this command creates an hello world example.

How do I create a new ReactJS app without the hello world sample code

```
npx create-react-app my-shop
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a React App without Create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50565466/how-to-create-a-react-app-without-create-react-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feature you're looking for is described at [CRA documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started#selecting-a-template)

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your react app as you like and push that into github.

In the future, when you want to create new react-app, instead of running "npx create-react-app", you just clone it from your github repository.